# Want some clarification on why this piece of code code works when getting data from an json object

Tags: angular

Here is a question I have being trying to get the why, mostly to fill my curiosity and understand more of how things work.

I have this function inside a service to get all the users

```
getallUsers() {
return this.http.get<User[]>(`/users`);
```

}

then in my component, I have

```
ngOnInit() {
this.loading = true;
this.service.getallUsers().pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.users = users['data'];
});
```

}

This code works, It will use a ngFor to loop over the different user names on users, my question is why before I was getting an error (even if the app would still work) saying that data is not part of the user when I was writing, users.data instead of users['data]

Answer (score 0):

By default, *users* inside subscribe callback is of type *Object*. In Typescript you cannot do users.data when 'users' type is an object. Instead do something like the following.

```
this.service.getallUsers().pipe(first()).subscribe((users: any) => {
  this.loading = false;
  this.users = users.data; // With type of users as any, you can do this.
});
```

Comment: Sorry - I thought this was OP query - 'my question is why before I was getting an error (even if the app would still work) saying that data is not part of the user when I was writing, users.data instead of users['data]'